# How to add jpanel to a specific cell of GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

in the below code, i created a GridLayot with 3 rows and 3 columns, what i want to do is,,to add jpanel_1 into 
a specifc cell of the Gridlayout, lets say in the grid cell number (2,3).

**Code**:

```
private void setUpGUI2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    jFrame_2 = new JFrame("Border Demo");
    GridLayout gridLayOut = new GridLayout(3,3);
    jFrame_2.setLayout(gridLayOut);

    jPanel_1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    jPanel_2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    jPanel_1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("title"));
    //jPanel_1.setBounds(30, 100, 110, 300);
    jPanel_1.add(jLabel_Hello, BorderLayout.EAST);

    jPanel_2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    //jPanel_2.setBounds(20, 50, 120, 80);
    jPanel_2.add(jLabel_Hello, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //jFrame_2.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
    jFrame_2.add(jPanel_1);//how to add jpanel_1 to a specific cell of Gridlayout defined above
    //jPanel_1.add(jPanel_2);
    jFrame_2.add(jPanel_2);
    jFrame_2.pack();
    jFrame_2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Calling setBounds is kind of useless

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). Further, describe more exactly what the purpose of leaving cells blank is.  E.G. is this a game where cell contents might change throughout the game (like chess or backgammon)?  Is this a design that just needs some padding? ..

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no chance. You need to add them one by one.
`frame.add(...); frame.add(...);`
I don't clearly understand what you want as result, but using `GridLayout(3, 3)` with only 2 panels is the same as use `GridLayout(0, 2)`.
P.S. Check out GridBagLayout - it can be more useful for you.

Comment: There (a chance), but you need to be creative? The other problem is, if the op "expects" the other cells to be laied out "virtual", so the spacing is the same, then even good old GridBagLayout won't work

Comment: @MadProgrammer you mean smth like ``add(new Component())``?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd use a JLabel as its transparent by default ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you could add "dummy" components (like a JLabel) to the cells you don't want to use. If I recall correctly, GridLayout will layout in col/row order

So of you wanted to add a component to the second column on the second row, you would have to add four JLabel's first, do pad out the layout